# Memory leak in application

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I run my code I get this error which will cause code execution to fail:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Why I receive this error?

I Believe because of using setState in a wrong way, but don't understand why.

This is my code:

```
class Activity extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.manager = new BleManager();
    this.state = {
      device1: "",
      device2: "",
      info: "",
      values: {},
      time: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scan1()
  }


  scan1() {
    console.log(" ")
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      if ((device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) || device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model)) {
        this.setState({device1: device.id})
        console.log("Device 1 ID: " + this.state.device1)
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        device.connect({autoConnect: true})
          .then(() => {
            this.scan2();
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.deviceService1(device);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            Alert.alert("Error");
            Actions.homepage();
          });
      }
    });
  }

  scan2() {
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      if ((device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model))|| device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) {
        this.setState({device2: device.id})
        console.log("Device 2 ID: " + this.state.device2)
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        device.connect({autoConnect: true})
          .then(() => {
            prova = this.manager.isDeviceConnected(dispositivo2)
            console.log(prova)
            this.deviceService2(device);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            Alert.alert(
              "Error"
            );
            Actions.homepage();
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Would you give a try moving the code block of `device.connect` as a callback after setState like `this.setState({device1: device.id},()=>{/* . */})`

Comment: @nivendha Thank you for your suggest, so i should put the device.connect methond inside the {/* . */} ??

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your scan2 function gets called AFTER your component has unmounted because `device.connect` is asynchronous. If that is the case, you probably don't have to worry about a memory leak

Comment: Yes the problem is in the scan2 function. But the connection failed for this error :(